# Why does the MinValue for an Int32 struct in C# have two minus signs infront of it?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I right-click `int` in my code and select "Go To Definition," Visual Studio opens a file titled "Int32 [from metadata]".  This file includes the following line:

```
public const Int32 MinValue = --2147483648;
```

What is the meaning of the double -- sign?

[image]

---

I am running Visual Studio 15.8.4.  Based on information in the comments, this is not reproducible on all versions of Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Where did this screenshot come from? [The source](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Int32.cs#L20) does not show this. It shows `unchecked((int)0x80000000)`

Comment: @vcsjones I just right clicked on int and selected go to definition...

Comment: Int32 metadata file...

Comment: _I just right clicked on int and selected go to definition_ - Not here.What system do you use?

Comment: @TaW I just added another image to be more clear... what am i missing?

Comment: no  there is no such thing in visual studio  I have resharper installed an I decompiled the struct you have a wrong plugin may  be

Comment: My `Int32` source has only one minus:  `public const Int32 MinValue = -2147483648;`

Comment: Hmm thats weird.. I'm not sure why mine is showing two minus signs..

Comment: I can repro with Visual Studio 15.8.4, but not with version 15.7.2.  And it seems [this guy](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/328206/c-metadata-int32-minvalue-is-wrong.html) can repro with 15.8.2.

Comment: This is likely just a quirk of whatever is decompiling the metadata. `--2147483648` won't even compile, you'll get a CS1059. If only present in a new version of Visual Studio, might be a bug.

Comment: @mjwills I have web essentials installed..

Comment: I can't repro using VS15.8.3, I'm getting `public const int MinValue = -2147483648;`. @psj01 are you using .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Comment: @ikkentim .net framework

Comment: @psj01 What is your Visual Studio version?

Comment: @BJMyers visual studio prof 2017

Comment: @psj01 Look in Help -> About.  There should be a line that looks like "Version 15.8.4"

Comment: `public const Int32 MinValue = -2147483648;` in Ver.: 15.7.4
The following would give you compile error
`public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = --2;
        }
    }`

Comment: VS 15.8.4 here - `public const Int32 MinValue = --2147483648;`

Comment: It is not a file, this "code" is auto-generated from the metadata in the assembly.  That can always go wrong, VS2017 is a bug shipping version and the 15.8.x updates have had many of them.  Use Help > Send Feedback > Report a Problem to let them know.

Comment: @BJMyers  mine is 15.8.4

Comment: Tracking bug. https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/29786

Answer (score 4):

[vcsjones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/492405/vcsjones) pointed to the newly created [bug report](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/29786) and this post appeared there:

> CyrusNajmabadi commented
>
> This is probably a bug i introduced when i fixed up how literals were
>   converted to syntax nodes. There was probably some special casing here
>   that added a - sign. And once the underlying helper was fixed we got
>   double negation.