# Why are there double minus signes?

Tags: c#

I'm dabbling in C# due to .Net Core nowadays. I see double minus signes in *System.Runtime* assembly as following.

```
    // Summary:
    //     Represents the largest possible value of an System.Int32. This field is constant.
    public const Int32 MaxValue = 2147483647;
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Represents the smallest possible value of System.Int32. This field is constant.
    public const Int32 MinValue = --2147483648;
```

Why is it being double? Is there any special meaning of it by contrary with unary minus?

@Edit, I see it's a bug in VS2017, but VS2019, as seen [on the link](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/29786). It is really intriguing!

Comment: means subtract 1 with the figure your putting double subtract. it is decrement operator

Comment: Question has been asked before here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52284085/why-does-the-minvalue-for-an-int32-struct-in-c-sharp-have-two-minus-signs-infron